# WiFi adapter wrongly detected

Tags: 16.04, drivers, wireless

I have dual booted my Dell G3- 3579 laptop. I am facing WiFi issue. Firstly it there appears no WiFi on the top bar. Secondly when i list all the PCI using the lspci command in the command line, the wireless adapter shows as Intel AC -9560.
On the other hand in windows when I check my WiFi adapter it shows as Intel AC-9462.
Pls suggest a permanent solution. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really matter as that info isn't used to pick a driver for the wifi as that is done by the results from `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`

You might see

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fd] (rev 78)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0050]
```

It is the 8086:24fd that will determine what driver is used in this case and since iwlwifi is the kernel driver for Intel wifi, the subsystem 0050 will also have to be a match for what is contained in the iwlwifi source code.

The description you see comes from user contributions at https://pci-ids.ucw.cz/ and you can download a newer version by

```
sudo update-pciids
```

If you actually want help to get wifi working, edit your post to include results from terminal for

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net
```

But I bet that your wifi will work with the 4.15 kernel, to install

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04
```

Reboot